# Any option to make Hadoop historyserver high available

Tags: hadoop

Any option to make Hadoop job historyserver high available ? I am using Hadoop 2.7

Also ResourceMgr high availability is not so much matured than of namenode .... even start-yarn.sh doesnot start the standby RM. Any out of the box solution for both of those ?

Comment: I don't think job history server supports HA, however it seems the next generation timeline server on hadoop 3.0 addresses this issue per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2928.

RM HA is pretty stable, do you see any particular issue surfaces? Start-yarn.sh should start both active and standby RMs, unless there is a configuration issue.